# Calcular Fecha a partir de sumarle cantidad de días y Formatearla

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de sumarle días a una fecha y luego formatearla para que sea legible por HUMANOS y posiblemente para ser insertada en una base de datos, pero no me funciona:

```js
function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
   dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
   console.log(dateObj);
   return dateObj;
}

var dias = 75; //Cantidad de Dias a Sumar
var now = new Date(); //Fecha Actual

console.log(now);

//Ejecucion:
var next = addDays(now, dias);

//Intento extraer

let yyyy = next.getFullYear();
let mm = next.getMonth();
let dd = next.getDate();

console.log(yyyy,mm,dd);
```

Como verán dentro de la Función el ouput es:

```
"2021-08-08T15:09:27.267Z"
```

pero al hacer el output del formateo me sale:

```
2021 7 8
```

**por que la diferencia en los output? y que estoy haciendo mal**

he trabajado con php y este seria el efecto/resultado esperado:

```
$enddate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+75 day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))));
echo $enddate;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb610029a403b39c30ac915280bf4dc1fb405e04

Comment: > El valor devuelto por getMonth() es un entero entre 0 y 11, donde 0 corresponde a Enero, 1 a Febrero y así sucesivamente

Comment: esto no solo pasa en js en el objeto devuelto por Calendar.getInstance() de kotlin y java tambien

Comment: es una pendejada de javascript por que getDate si te retorna el numero de día y no inicia desde 0 quien será el papa de la aberración... por que aplica un concepto distinto para año, mes y día … con métodos que llevan un nombre similar, cualquiera esperaría que getMonthPosition si retorne la posición del mes iniciando desde 0

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez es una pregunta que se hizo ya hace mucho, la utilidad de ello es para que se puedan usar matrices

Comment: no me parece tan malo supongamos que haces un array con los nombres del mes que vas a hacer con la primera posición la dejas vacía?, si empezara con el uno te tocaria o restarle 1

Comment: @junior en ese caso debería existir un método especifico para manejar los meses por posiciones: `getMonthPosition`, si se dan cuenta ... el concepto utilizados para `getDate` cambia completamente en comparación con `getMonth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque `getMonth()` comienza en 0 y no en 1, por eso siempre hay que sumarle 1 al mes, para que este correcto

También debes considerar el el estándar javascript EMAC esta en continuo desarrollo te dejo las notas del reporte realizado al MDN de javascript en github:

> Afortunadamente, probablemente tendremos una propuesta temporal en la
> especificación de ECMAScript el próximo año y luego podremos
> rellenarla con polyfill o ajustarla según sea necesario. En
> particular, Temporal.PlainDate y otras rutinas temporales que aceptan
> y devuelven números de mes, utilizan números de mes ISO indexados.
> Esto debería hacer que los cálculos de fechas sean mucho menos
> propensos a errores.
>
> Después de eso, espero que la mejor práctica sea evitar Date para los
> cálculos y convertir según sea necesario.

Link Relacionados:

https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/5298#issuecomment-849457407
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal
https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindate.html#new-Temporal-PlainDate
https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html#converting-between-temporal-types-and-legacy-date