# Dar formato a una fecha con javascript

Tags: javascript

**El problema es el siguiente:**
Obtengo de una base de datos un dato tipo fecha con el formato yyyy-mm-dd, lo almaceno en una variable y lo formateo con javascript como quiero q sea la salida.

```
var fecha = libro.fechaPublicacionLibro;
var d = new Date(fecha);

var meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre'];

var dia = d.getDate();
var mes = meses[d.getMonth()];
var year = d.getFulllYear();

console.log(dia + "de" + mes + "de" + year)
```

**Un caso de prueba:**
 La fecha almacenada en la base de datos es 2021-09-22 por lo q la salida que deseo es 22 de septiembre de 2021, pero no es esa la q obtengo sino 21 de septiembre de 2021, es decir con un dia de atraso.
**Para ejemplificar mas el problema otro caso de prueba:**
La fecha en la base de datos es 2021-09-01 y la salida que obtengo es 31 de agosto de 2021.
Siempre un día de atraso. ¿Cúal puede ser el problema?

Comment: agrégale `+1` a var `dia = d.getDate();` y queda así: `dia = 1 + d.getDate();`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Calcular Fecha a partir de sumarle cantidad de días y Formatearla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454826/calcular-fecha-a-partir-de-sumarle-cantidad-de-d%c3%adas-y-formatearla)

Answer (score 0):

- Es posible que tenas problemas con tu zona horaria:
- Prueba a crear una fecha con UTC 0:

```
  function createDateAsUTC(dateYmd) {
    var dateYmdSplited = dateYmd.split('-');
    var y = Number(dateYmdSplited[0]);
    var m = Number(dateYmdSplited[1]) - 1;
    var d = Number(dateYmdSplited[2])

    return new Date(Date.UTC(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0))
}

var fecha = "2021-09-01";
var d = createDateAsUTC(fecha);

var meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre'];

var dia = d.getDate();
var mes = meses[d.getMonth()];
var year = d.getFullYear();

console.log(dia + " de " + mes + " de " + year)
```